# Copy the files from one folder to another folder using applescript got an error

Tags: applescript

I am trying to dupe the file from one folder to another folder with below codes.

on run {input, parameters}

```
set collectPaths to {}
repeat with i from 1 to (input count)
    set collectPaths to item i of input as string
end repeat

tell application "System Events"
    set fileList to (every folder of folder collectPaths whose name is "Old")
    if (count of fileList) is equal to 0 then
        tell application "Finder"
            set x to make new folder at input with properties {name:"Old"}
        end tell
    else
        set x to fileList
    end if
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set fileList to (every file of folder collectPaths whose name extension is "ai")
    repeat with i from 1 to count of fileList
        set theItem to item i of fileList
        tell application "Finder"
            duplicate the file theItem to the folder x
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

end run

But I got an error as **"The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Finder got an error: Can’t make alias of folder "Old" of folder "untitled folder 2" of folder "Desktop" of folder "asuvathdhamank" of folder "Users" of startup disk into type string.”**

Please help me out from this and dupe the file on that Old folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your first loop is pointless. At the exit, CollectPath will contain the last item of input and do nothing else. To run input elements, simply use this :

```
repeat with collectPaths in inputs
   display dialog "Hello, " & collectPaths
   -- put your whole routine in this loop
end repeat
```

to simply create a new folder if needed (no need to check if it exists):

```
do shell script "mkdir -p" & space & quoted form of (posix path of collectPaths & ":Old")
```

You have to be familiar with "quoted form" and "posix path", "posix file", HFS and POSIX paths. There are a lot of examples anywhere. You can browse StandardAdditions dictionary in the Script Editor's Library about these terms.

You have to figure out what's in the 'input' is it a list of paths, a path ?
put "log input" , "log class of input", "log  collectPaths" in your script at critical points to know more about what's going on.

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks for checking and your comments, i will implement your suggestion and let know if i have any error